# Elastic layout with media query - margins not correct

Tags: html, css, layout, fluid-layout

I'm trying to make an elastic layout which aligns both the left and the right margins with the far left and far right of the page, no matter how many items are shown on that line.

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/U2W72/1/

```
.thumb {
    float: left;
    width:16%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    background: pink;
    height: 200px;
}
.thumb:nth-child(5n) {
    margin-right: 0px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 3px red;
}
.thumb:nth-child(5n+1) {
    margin-left: 0px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 3px blue;
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .thumb, .thumb:nth-child(1n) {
        width:21%;
        margin-left: 2%;
        margin-right: 2%;
        margin-bottom: 4%;
        box-shadow: 0 0;
    }
    .thumb:nth-child(4n) {
        margin-right:0;
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 3px yellow;
    }
    .thumb:nth-child(4n+1) {
        margin-left:0;
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 3px blue;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .thumb, .thumb:nth-child(1n) {
        width:46%;
    }
    .thumb:nth-child(2n) {
        margin-right:0;
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 3px gray;
    }
    .thumb:nth-child(2n+1) {
        margin-left:0;
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 3px blue;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .thumb, .thumb:nth-child(1n) {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 1px;
    }
}
#left {
    float: left
}
#right {
    float: right
}
```

I believe I am using nth child correctly to remove the margin from the left and right most pink boxes so they align but it doesn't look correct when I run it. Can anyone show me where I am going wrong please?

Comment: what do you mean by 'not correct'  (see you are using example are provided in another post/question)

Comment: you want this http://jsfiddle.net/U2W72/3/?

Comment: @MiljanPuzović You've got it nailed! The only issue is it isn't correct when there are five across (i.e the one with the red box)

Comment: Ahhh, I'm currently on netbook, didn't see red box because of small resolution :)

Comment: @MiljanPuzović the example i provided in first place was using vw units too , he drop them apparently http://jsfiddle.net/N3VRM/6/ from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724487/elastic-layout-ensuring-layout-always-aligns

Comment: I removed vw units and I've increased width of boxes inside media queries, because if you remove margins below 400px, on example, then you will have just one div with 100% width. I did the same for the rest of code

Comment: Point is, just calculate correct width in function of margins. width of all elements in a row + all margins of those elements = 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove the margins from first and last element on the row, total of widths+margins isn't 100%. Example:
if you have 5 boxes with width 16% and margin left and right 2%, then total is 100%. But when you remove 2% margin from first box and 2% margin from last box, then total is 96%. Make sense?